# How do surfaces absorb and reflect light at the atomic level, and what does that have to do with color?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light

This is sort of a 2 part question that I'm really struggling to figure out.

1. When white light (which as far as I understand, is just a composition of most electromagnetic frequencies) bounces off, say, an apple, a red frequency is reflected and all other frequencies are absorbed. How does this happen? I read [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/112824/color-of-macroscopic-objects-on-molecular-level), but it doesn't provide enough detail for me
2. How do the surfaces actually **absorb** the light? What is going on atomically? The law of conservation of energy implies that light's energy must be conserved.  Intuitively it's converted to heat, but how does that actually happen? Since heat (thermal energy) is just kinetic energy, is it the result of the induced oscillation of the electrons in the atoms, which, in turn, is caused by resonance from the EMF wave hitting the atoms? If so, why is that oscillation only caused by that frequency of light? If not, then how does the conversion to heat occur?

Any help is appreciated, and preferably the more in-depth (without going into quantum physics), the better.

Answer (score 1):

Light is an wave in the electromagnetic field. It's useful to model light as being made up of many little superposed waves, each with a particular specific energy amount. The energy amount of each little wave corresponds to its color. White light is an electromagnetic wave that can be modeled as being made of many little superposed waves of a multitude of different colors.

Most of the time, light doesn't interact with atoms very much at all. Atoms are very picky about what kind of light they'll interact with because they have a very limited number of quantized energy levels and can only absorb light that has just the right amount of energy.

When light interacts with a solid, however, it interacts with not just atoms, but with all the electromagnetic fields that hold the atoms together into molecules and all the fields that hold the molecules together into a solid. Everything in the solid is constantly wiggling and jiggling around, and all the electromagnetic fields holding everything together are constantly shifting.

There are three possibilities. In most materials, all three are present at once.

First, the light could interact with the material in a very regular and ordered way, giving it a little jiggle so that the electromagnetic field found on the far end looks pretty much identical to the electromagnetic field of the incident light. This is *transmission*. When you can see through a solid, it is because of this.

Second, the energy of the electromagnetic wave could be absorbed by the solid, if the solid has ways to store energy in that frequency. Each absorption interaction is hypothetically quantized, but there are so many possible different-energy-level interactions available that this in principle quantization doesn't matter. This is *absorption*. When an opaque surface looks dark when illuminated, it is because of this.

Third, the electromagnetic wave could interact with the solid's fields in such a way as to induce an equal and opposite response that will destructively interfere in the original direction, but will resemble a reflection of the incident wave as if the wave had bounced off the surface. This is *reflection*. When a surface appears bright when illuminated, it is because of this. (A very smooth polished surface will appear conventionally mirror-reflective because the surface at the point of interaction doesn't point in all different directions as it does on a microscopically rough surface.)

Different materials are more or less transmissive to certain ranges of color (energy amounts); more or less absorptive to certain ranges of color; and more or less reflective of certain ranges of color. A red apple doesn't just reflect red light. It reflects all frequencies of visible light. (If you point a low-wattage green laser pointer at a red apple; you'll see a green dot). It absorbs all frequencies of visible light. (If you put a red apple under a red heat lamp, it will get warm.) It even transmits a very small amount. (Try cutting a thin wafer of an apple, including the peel, and holding it to the tip of a flashlight in a dark room.) Redder colors are reflected and transmitted more and absorbed less compared to other colors, so the apple appears red when illuminated with white light, or when white light is shone through it.

Comment: Could you explain reflection a bit more. Everything else makes sense.